# JSTree binding issue with href

Tags: jquery, html, jstree

I've got JStree working with the binding function that opens the href link of the node.
However it has now broken my Bootstrap tabs section.

```
$('#jstree').bind("select_node.jstree", function (e, data) {
var href = data.node.a_attr.href;
document.location.href =  href;

<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
<li class="active"><a  href="#1" data-toggle="tab" id=tab1>
Tab1
</a>
</li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content ">
<div class="tab-pane active" id="1">
//some content
</div>
```

Is there a better way of binding the node to its href?

```
 document.location.href =  href;
```

seems to apply the href to the whole DOM and not specifically to the node.. Therefore affecting all href links and the tabs feature...i'm guessing...

Any help on this matter?

Thanks

Update:
It seems the issue is not with the bind. But with the jstree itself... Once ive removed it...

```
    $('#jstree').jstree({
  'plugins': ["sort"],
    'core' : {
        'data' : {
    'url' : "fetch_tree.php", 
     'data' : function (node) {
     return { 'id' : node.id };
    },
        "dataType" : "json"
    }
    },'check_callback' : true
})
```

The bootstrap tabs feature works...

Answer (score 0):

So i found a 'workaround'

Using..

```
<a  data-target="#1" data-toggle="tab" id=tab1>
```

instead of

```
<a  href="#1" data-toggle="tab" id=tab1>
```

allowed tabs to work alogside jstree. But i couldn't find a proper solution.